# Parameter passing in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, parameter-passing, heapsort

So I'm trying to implement heap sort, and I'm having trouble with the parameter passing part. In general, I have this:

```
int main() {

int array[5];

heapsize = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array));

std::cout << "Input 5 integers separated by spaces:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> array[i];
}
cout << "main length of a: " << (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) << endl;


heapSort(array);

cout << "final output:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    cout << array[i] << "  ";

return 0;
}
```

where I read in an array, and pass that into `heapSort(array)`.

Then I do:

```
void heapSort(int A[])
{
int n; 
n = (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])); 
cout << "This is n: " << n << endl; //prints out n = 1 
build_max_heap(A); 
}
```

I mean to pass the `array[5]` into `heapsort(int A[])`, so why is the length showing up as 1?

Comment: In case it isn't mentioned in the duplicate, in C (and by extension in C++) a function `void heapSort(int A[])` really is `void heapSort(int* A)`. This leads to all kinds of confusion.

Comment: You should pass in two parameters: the array and its size.

Comment: @JonnyHenly would have two parameters, but I'm required to implement it with only 1.

Comment: @ocean800 they probably want you to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: @juanchopanza I didn't completely understand from the other question... basically, I can't find the length of the array by doing `sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])`?

Comment: @ocean800 You can't find the length of an array from a pointer to an element of that array. A pointer is just a pointer.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Or they want them to figure out how to pass a reference to an array, or a pointer to an array :-)